# Activemq server connection from activemq app

Tags: java, jms, jetty, activemq-classic

My greetings!

I have an activemq console app that is fully functional. I am using JMS + Spring config for it. I need to connect it to an activemq server, which is on jetty (the official admin web app from amq). I tried to set the same port in the xml config in my app, like

```
<amq:transportConnectors>
        <!--amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://192.168.1.3:60000" enableStatusMonitor="true" /-->
        <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:61616" enableStatusMonitor="true" />
</amq:transportConnectors>
```

But still there is no result. I would really appreciate your help.

EDIT:
ok, I have also found that I have to attach an import:

```
    <import resource="${activemq.base}/conf/jetty.xml" />
```

But is there a way to set the activemq.base variable to my context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is the decision. All you need is just to comment out all of the amq config xml code and leave just amq:connectionFactory with brokerUrl set to the same port as the activemq web console. Then start both of them and enjoy.